Disable workspace wipe out by default for checkout scm in Jenkins
On each checkout scm step run the workspace is wiped out by default (log: Wiping out workspace first.), but I do not want that to happen as I am clearing it at the beginning with cleanWs(). Does anyone knows how I can disable this?
This is the schema of my pipeline code.
cleanWs()
# Some code that alters the workspace
checkout scm
# After checkout I do not see changes made before running it as it is wiping out the workspace

P.S. I ve found out filesystem option with clearWorkspace parameter in the documentation that may help but I do not have a clue how to pass that parameter. Can anyone help with the call? Tried: checkout scm: [filesystem: [clearWorkspace: false]] and checkout scm: [clearWorkspace: false] but getting the invocation error.

checkout scm: [$class: 'MercurialSCM', source: 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo', clean: true, credentialsId: '1234-5678-abcd'], poll: false
It is based on what kind of $class / scm you are using behind the scenes. An example can be found here. The list of all the possible $class / scm options (and their params, after click-trough) are found here

If you do not specify any class, what is the default one used? And how can I set filesystem parameters as they are not nested under any class?

You can't use filesystem parameters if you don't use filesystem. I am unsure about what default one would be used if none are specified;  Maybe the one linked to the possible scm used before or set in the job config
